# Hide the 'Gallery Settings' section of the Gallery tab of the media Thickbox

Tags: gallery, thickbox

When I invoke the media uploader from a certain page, I'm looking for a way to hide all of the 'Gallery Settings' options at the bottom of the Gallery tab. I have set a referrer (`dd-options-footer`), so I can check that to ensure the code is only added for my desired page, but it seems that whatever I add does not work.

I've tried adding both custom CSS and JS to do this, but it appears that WP overrides this in `wp-admin/js/gallery-min.js` when it outputs the content of the tab.

Anyone know how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David, I'm not sure if you're trying to disable the whole gallery (plus the settings) or only its fields. For the first option, you should try do deregister the `admin-gallery` script:

```
function disable_gallery() {
    $post_id = (int) $_GET['post_id'];

    // Check for your post / page ID
    if( $post_id == 343  ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'admin-gallery' );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_gallery' );
```